# IP Camera (RTSP) and QR codes

Tags: c#, opencv, rtsp, ip-camera, rtsp-client

I am working on a project that would enable my application to connect to one or more IP cameras (RTSP, H264) and detect any QR codes. The library I want to use for the QR Code detection is the ZXing Project.

One I can capture the frame from the camera and decode it to an Bitmap, the QR code detection is easy. I am struggling to find a library or two to connect to the IP camera, and take still images at a given internal. Real-time would be nice.

I have tried EMGU (OpenCV) port for C#. It kinda works, but its very slow and will hang one or two minutes into it. The camera I am using is 720p. I am working with the net7mma library now, but I am having trouble decoding the H264 frame to a bitmap.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that others have found success using openRTSP:
https://superuser.com/questions/766437/capture-rtsp-stream-from-ip-camera-and-store

Note the -m option for outputting single frames:
http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/